# jQuery selector not working on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to access each td on the table but it returns nothing. I try to use the jquery each function like this:

```
$('div.daterangepicker > div.calendar-table > table.table-condensed > tr').each(function(index, element){ 
console.log(index); 
});
```

or this

```
$('table.table-condensed > tbody > tr').each(function(index, element){
 console.log(element);
});
```

Here's the html element where I want to use the jquery selector

```
<div class="daterangepicker dropdown-menu ltr single opensleft show-calendar">
      <div class="calendar left single">
        <div class="daterangepicker_input">
          <div class="calendar-table">
            <table class="table-condensed">
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td class="weekend off available" data-title="r0c0">24</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c1">25</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c2">26</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c3">27</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c4">28</td><td class="off available" data-title="r0c5">29</td>
                 <td class="weekend off available" data-title="r0c6">30</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td class="weekend available" data-title="r1c0">1</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c1">2</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c2">3</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c3">4</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c4">5</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c5">6</td>
                 <td class="weekend available" data-title="r1c6">7</td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I made a codepen with the actual code: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLvwXe). 
I dunno why some answers which seems to be working doesn't work with my code.

Comment: `div.calendar-table` is not a child of `div.daterangepicker`, so your first selector fails right there already.

Comment: your selector is targetting immediate descendants with `>` but not all descendants are immediate

Comment: Your second approach works fine unless you expected to get something else?

Answer (score 2):

The part of the selector:

```
table.table-condensed > tr
```

Says "get table rows that are direct children of my table" - but they are actually one more level down...

```
table.table-condensed > tbody > tr
```

And if you don't care so much about it being exactly so, you can just find all descendants:

```
table.table-condensed tr
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('table.table-condensed  tbody  tr').each(function(){
    $(this).find("td").each(function(key,value){
      $(".result").append($(value).text()+" | ");
    });
    $(".result").append("<hr>");
});
```

```css
.result{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="daterangepicker dropdown-menu ltr single opensleft show-calendar">
      <div class="calendar left single">
        <div class="daterangepicker_input">
          <div class="calendar-table">
            <table class="table-condensed">
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td class="weekend off available" data-title="r0c0">24</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c1">25</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c2">26</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c3">27</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c4">28</td><td class="off available" data-title="r0c5">29</td>
                 <td class="weekend off available" data-title="r0c6">30</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td class="weekend available" data-title="r1c0">1</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c1">2</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c2">3</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c3">4</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c4">5</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c5">6</td>
                 <td class="weekend available" data-title="r1c6">7</td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `(class > childClass)` means the child must be a DIRECT descendant ([source](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)). So you can't skip levels. Try using either

[Closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

or

[Children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to select the `td` elements using the children selector. `table.tablec-condensed td`  will select the `td` elements from all `table` elements having `table-condensed` class. Which should be enough.

You can make it slightly more specific by adding `daterangepicker` in the front: `$('.daterangepicker table.table-condensed td')`

```js
$('.daterangepicker table.table-condensed td').each(function(index, element){
 console.log(element);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="daterangepicker dropdown-menu ltr single opensleft show-calendar">
      <div class="calendar left single">
        <div class="daterangepicker_input">
          <div class="calendar-table">
            <table class="table-condensed">
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td class="weekend off available" data-title="r0c0">24</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c1">25</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c2">26</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c3">27</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c4">28</td><td class="off available" data-title="r0c5">29</td>
                 <td class="weekend off available" data-title="r0c6">30</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td class="weekend available" data-title="r1c0">1</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c1">2</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c2">3</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c3">4</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c4">5</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c5">6</td>
                 <td class="weekend available" data-title="r1c6">7</td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop each `td` for a `tr`.The first `.each` will iterate each `tr`.Again loop each `tr` to get `td`

```js
$('table.table-condensed  tr').each(function(index, element) {
  $(element).each(function(el, em) {
    console.log($(em).text())
  })
});
```

```css
or this $('table.table-condensed > tbody > tr').each(function(index, element) {
  console.log(element);
}

);
Here's the html element where I want to use the jquery selector
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="daterangepicker dropdown-menu ltr single opensleft show-calendar">
  <div class="calendar left single">
    <div class="daterangepicker_input">
      <div class="calendar-table">
        <table class="table-condensed">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="weekend off available" data-title="r0c0">24</td>
              <td class="off available" data-title="r0c1">25</td>
              <td class="off available" data-title="r0c2">26</td>
              <td class="off available" data-title="r0c3">27</td>
              <td class="off available" data-title="r0c4">28</td>
              <td class="off available" data-title="r0c5">29</td>
              <td class="weekend off available" data-title="r0c6">30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="weekend available" data-title="r1c0">1</td>
              <td class="available" data-title="r1c1">2</td>
              <td class="available" data-title="r1c2">3</td>
              <td class="available" data-title="r1c3">4</td>
              <td class="available" data-title="r1c4">5</td>
              <td class="available" data-title="r1c5">6</td>
              <td class="weekend available" data-title="r1c6">7</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual Jquery script will be:

```js
$('.table-condensed tr').each(function(index, element){
  $(element).find('td').each(function(i, e){
   console.log(e.innerHTML);
  });
  console.log('\n');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="daterangepicker dropdown-menu ltr single opensleft show-calendar">
      <div class="calendar left single">
        <div class="daterangepicker_input">
          <div class="calendar-table">
            <table class="table-condensed">
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td class="weekend off available" data-title="r0c0">24</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c1">25</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c2">26</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c3">27</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c4">28</td><td class="off available" data-title="r0c5">29</td>
                 <td class="weekend off available" data-title="r0c6">30</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td class="weekend available" data-title="r1c0">1</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c1">2</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c2">3</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c3">4</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c4">5</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c5">6</td>
                 <td class="weekend available" data-title="r1c6">7</td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is both wrong and unnecessarily long. The `>` "child combinator" selector will only select immediate children, hence ignoring the element you're after. [Learn more about the child combinator selector at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors).

Always try using a shorter, direct selector, for example:

`$('.your-table tr');`

Answer (score 0):

According to jquery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) the `E > F` selector works only for first-level descendants.
So you can find the `td`using:

```
$('table.table-condensed > tbody > tr > td')

//better option
$('table.table-condensed').find('td')
```

```js
console.log($('table.table-condensed > tbody > tr > td').length);
console.log($('tr > td').length);
console.log($('table.table-condensed').find('td').length);

$('table.table-condensed').find('td').css({'background': 'red'})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="daterangepicker dropdown-menu ltr single opensleft show-calendar">
      <div class="calendar left single">
        <div class="daterangepicker_input">
          <div class="calendar-table">
            <table class="table-condensed">
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td class="weekend off available" data-title="r0c0">24</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c1">25</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c2">26</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c3">27</td>
                 <td class="off available" data-title="r0c4">28</td><td class="off available" data-title="r0c5">29</td>
                 <td class="weekend off available" data-title="r0c6">30</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td class="weekend available" data-title="r1c0">1</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c1">2</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c2">3</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c3">4</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c4">5</td>
                 <td class="available" data-title="r1c5">6</td>
                 <td class="weekend available" data-title="r1c6">7</td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```